# How to limit speed/amount/performance of coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, webclient, kotlin-coroutines

I want to fetch data from external microservice in a loop a several hundred thousand times using  Spring and Kotlin with coroutines. Next I want to modify this data and send it to this microservice back.
I do not want to DDOS this microservice. What are the ways to limit performance/speed/amount of coroutines?

Comment: Use a connection pool with a bounded queue and a sensible amount of max threads.

Answer (score 0):

"do not want to DDOS this microservice"
First, determine how you measure allowable rate of access to the microservice. Is it number of messages in a second, or is it total size of messages, or some more complex measurement?

For example, let we want to limit the minimal period between invocation of microservice, say, as 100 ms. Then just call `delay(100L)` before next invocation of the microservice.